# Commutation relation confusion of ladder operators in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

Suppose that $X$ and $N$ are operators such that they follow the commutation relation $$[N,X]=cX$$ for some scalar c. In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_operator) Wikipedia article it is shown that if $|n \rangle$ is some eigenstate of the operator $N$ with the eigenvalue equation $N|n \rangle=n|n \rangle,$ then X will act on the eigenstate $|n \rangle$ such that $$NX|n \rangle=\left(XN+[N,X]\right)|n \rangle $$ $$=XN|n \rangle+[N,X]|n \rangle$$ $$=Xn|n \rangle+cX|n\rangle$$ $$=(n+c)X|n\rangle.$$ I understand steps $2$ and $4$ but do not understand $1$ and $3$. What is going on in the first and third lines of the work, i.e why do we obtain  $NX|n \rangle=\left(XN+[N,X]\right)|n \rangle$ for $XN$?

Comment: What happens if you begin from the definition of the commutator as $[N,X] = NX-XN = cX$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operators do not always commute, and to compute the commutator we can use the definition $[N,X] = NX - XN$ applied to an arbitrary function.

Here you are being told that the operators $N$ and $X$ follow commutation relation $[N,X] = cX$

So at step 1, we can manipulate the commutator definition to find $NX = XN+[N,X]$

At step 3, the operators are applied according to the eigenvalue equation, and the commutation relation we are given as $cX$. That is $N$ as $n$ and, $[N,X]$ as $cX$, where we can then pull the like terms in step 4.

Comment: Cant believe I didnt see that, thanks for clearing everything up!